# What are the node.js frameworks for real-time model synchronization between browser and server?

Tags: node.js

What are the node.js frameworks for real-time model synchronization?

I am aware of only racer (https://github.com/codeparty/racer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look into:

- node-object-sync https://github.com/jonashuckestein/node-object-sync ,
- backbone.iobind https://github.com/logicalparadox/backbone.iobind or
- backbone.io https://github.com/scttnlsn/backbone.io

but racer / derby is not bad either. These are just options, you should pick one whichever is most appropriate for you.

Comment: I'll add to that that there was once now.js but I do not encourage using it since it looks inactive.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you continue using Racer, or, if you are interested in a more mature framework based on Racer, I strongly suggest you try out [Derby](http://derbyjs.com/).

If you are coming from Rails, I would totally suggest you go all in with [Derby](http://derbyjs.com/). If you are looking for a Rails Backbone alternative for Node, try [Backbone.io](https://github.com/scttnlsn/backbone.io)

Answer (score 0):

Adding for completeness:  Meteor DDP:  https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/livedata/DDP.md

The best way to use it is to go all-in on Meteor; I doubt that the code is useful or usable outside of Meteor.   The spec may be, though.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a set of libraries a little while back: http://github.com/Rekord/rekord

It also has all the features in a model library you would expect.

Answer (score -2):

For real-time application development, currently, we have [Derby](http://derbyjs.com) and [Tower.js](http://towerjs.org)

Comment: Question is about framework for model sync. Derby internally uses racer.